# how can I say "the book was written by him" in chinese?

Tags: translation

I need to write a similar sentence with not skilled chinese but i don t know how
Write any similar sentence you think can help. Thank you in advance

Comment: 这本书是他写的  or  这本书是他编的. Is that what you are looking for?